# Audio Button doesn't play

Tags: audio, sdk, playback

I am using audio tool box and selected the following code to play a 30 second m4a file.

```
(IBAction)playFullSongButton:(id)sender 
{

    CFBundleRef mainBundle= CFBundleGetMainBundle();

    CFURLRef soundFileUrlRef;

    soundFileUrlRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, 

    (CFStringRef)@"fullsong",CFSTR("m4a"),NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileUrlRef, &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}
```

it works with all my 2 and 3 second files but Im assuming 30 seconds is too long . any suggestions? please bare in mind that I am totally new to this Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, all i had to do was install the avfoundation framework. I guess audio toolbox doesn't support large audio files!